# Why does referencing a non-exported class not generate a transpilation error?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, module, tsc, tsconfig

I'm relatively new to both Typescript and Javascript (and node.js), from a Java background, but learning fast the painful way. I recently converted from one giant Typescript file with a number of classes to using multiple classes.  This took some research, and I don't claim to fully understand the 2+ different systems of Javascript imports.  But I'm using the `import {ClassName} from './{Classname}'` syntax, and making sure that `Classname` starts with `export class ClassName`.  This was initially working great.  In particular, coming from a Java background and being dependent on compiler errors, I appreciated that Netbeans would detect errors in my importing, and `tsc` agreed.  Add an import, try again, and everything made sense.

Until it stopped working, that is no errors were generated with wrong (?) code.  At runtime I got `ReferenceError: ClassToBeImportedis not defined`.  Sure enough, `ClassToBeImported` was not being imported.  I expect adding `import {ClassToBeImported} from './{ClassToBeImported}` would solve it.  (Am I right?  Easier answered than tested in this case.)  What bothers me is that this was a runtime error this time instead of an IDE/transpiler error.

While trying to come up with a minimal example, I think the problem is that the referenced file wasn't being exported.  If I add/remove `export` from `export class NeedsToBeImported` the error comes/goes respetively.

This will generate an error (`Cannot find name 'ClassToBeImported'.`):

```
// in file MainClass.ts
export class MainClass{
    constructor(){
        let x = ClassToBeImported.SOME_FIELD;
    }
}

// in file ClassToBeImported.ts, same folder
export class ClassToBeImported{
    static SOME_FIELD : string = "data";
}
```

This will not, until runtime:

```
// in file MainClass.ts
export class MainClass{
    constructor(){
        let x = ClassToBeImported.SOME_FIELD;
    }
}

// in file ClassToBeImported.ts, same folder
class ClassToBeImported{
    static SOME_FIELD : string = "data";
}
```

So the primary question is what the heck is going on.  ("Why does referencing a non-exported class not generate a transpilation error?")  The secondary question is if there's anything I can do to make this "safer" on myself.  If there's some option I can turn on in `tsconfig.json` (currently targeting es2015) to make it stricter it could be useful.

Comment: what typescript version are you using?

Comment: If you are missing the `export`, TSC probably doesn't recognise `ClassToBeImported.ts` as a module. And as a script, the `class ClassToBeImported` is a global, so it works fine. You just have to included the script in your page alongside the others.

Comment: @shusson Actually I'm not sure.  `tsc --version` returns 2.6.1, but 3.4.2 is in my package.json.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of source files in JavaScript and TypeScript: **scripts** and **modules**.

I quote [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

For example, you could load the file `ClassToBeImported.js` in a `<script>` tag in a web page, and then the `ClassToBeImported` class will be available as a global variable.